# Policy on lmgtfy links

Tags: discussion

What is our policy on [lmgtfy](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lmgtfy) links? Some questions show no research effort by the OP, and while most of the times, it is sufficient to suggest a google search, [some questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87519/what-is-hydel-electricity) seem to be begging for a lmgtfy comment. Is it acceptable, or is it considered rude / inappropriate?

Comment: _Some questions show no research
effort by the OP_ Like yours?  Just kidding.  Next time you should try to search in mother meta, they've asked almost everything.

Comment: Yes, nice idea.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5033/2451

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The overarching "Be nice" directive means that LMGTFY links are right out.

Yes, some people are unselfconsciously out to take advantage of us, and yes this is very, *very* annoying. None-the-less we're going to be the better people here.

Feel free to vote to close such question [when you have the privilege](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Or to [flag them](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) if you don't.

Comment: Alright, makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

Please don't make any lmgtfy comments. They will be deleted.

See: [Ban LMGTFY (let me google that for you) links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) and [Is LMGTFY frowned upon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109713/is-lmgtfy-frowned-upon)