# Use of lmgtfy.com

Tags: discussion

Naming no names, but please can we have a ban on using lmgtfy.com in comments. I appreciate how frustrating it can be that users post questions without having done the most basic Google search. But pointing them at lmgtfy.com is just snide and unbecoming of an august company such as ourselves.

Just downvote, vote to close and then imagine yourself interviewing the offender for a job at your university in years to come.

**Later**: doh, I showed [insufficient effort](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question) in checking for duplicates. This was discussed in [Policy on lmgtfy links](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/policy-on-lmgtfy-links). Oh well, it probably doesn't hurt to jog memories.

Comment: I thought there *was* such a ban.

Comment: @dmckee I think SO bans it but I don't think it's system-wide.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5226/2451 Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5033/2451

Comment: Point taken....

Comment: @Jimnosperm Don't fret it too much--we all get frustrated from time to time[1]--just try not to put too much of your emotion into the on-site content. I sometime just walk away from the site for a few hours. [1] Well, maybe John doesn't: his onsite persona has the patience of a saint. A good example to all and we appreciate it.

Comment: If I may add a dissenting opinion; the mother meta post seems more written for things that are googleable but not immediately apparent from doing so. If we all remember the "Do Fire Tornados Exist?" question, that was answered by typing "fire tornado" into google and getting pictures of them as the first hit. I think such blatant laziness should be punished by a lmgtfy link. We post the wiki articles, we post google search links, we do everything but use lmgtfy. Does the extra step really make so much difference?

Comment: And quite frankly, voting to close a question as insufficient effort is just as humiliating as posting a lmgtfy link. They both say "this was easy and you could have done it yourself. Waste your own time next time"

Comment: I'm not always good at working out what people will and won't find upsetting, but at least my VTC pointed the OP to a post that explains in detail what we expect before posting a question. A lmgtfy link feels to me like just saying f**k off.

Comment: Okay. I'll give you mine was more brash. Both still say f\*\*k off. But your way says it in the politest possible manner (that is, politest while still saying f**k off)

Comment: No, mine was constructive because it explained exactly what is required to avoid being told to to go forth and multiply in the future.

Comment: I don't feel qualified to argue how people interpret messages. I merely speculate that being told what is required to avoid being told things like this indicates one hasn't met requirements. Logically, if you haven't met the requirements to avoid being told something, directing you to these requirements must be a form of telling you that something. It's a polite and constructive form. But the way I see it, it still tells them to "go forth and multiply" (I like the way you put that). But again, I'm not qualified to argue this, so it's best I drop the issue and accept the views of the majority

Comment: @Jimnosperm I really don't agree that both VTC and "lmgtfy-ing" give off the same vibe... at all.

Answer (score 15):

Come on John, [haven't you done a google search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+lmgtfy)? :)

Seriously though, as Qmechanic linked to in the comments on your question, [the "be nice" policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/policy-on-lmgtfy-links) basically tells people to not to it.

The [post on mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) says that banning it will just incur performance penalties and instead you should leave a comment telling that person they should be nicer. They take the approach that people being disrespectful will just be disrespectful in *other* ways, and so banning the links doesn't really help anything.

Comment: Moderators! tpg is being mean to me!!!!

Comment: The "official" "policy" is that lmgtfy links aren't banned if they're funny enough :-P (seriously though, the rationale behind banning them is that they're considered rude, but if you're not using it to be insulting, it's not a problem)

Comment: Ouch the irony.

Answer (score 2):

There's never any need to use LMGTFY in a comment.

The comment

> [LMGTFY]

translates as

> I am (please check all that apply):
>   [  ] annoyed,
>   [  ] frustrated
>   [  ] stressed,
>   [  ] an asshole,
>   [  ] having a bad day.
>
> The answer to your question can easily be found using a search engine so please do that. If you can't understand what you find, or why it answers your question, please ask a more specific question about the parts you don't understand.

The commenter's mood or disposition are irrelevant to the question and likely to change, rendering the comment partially obsolete. Therfore, they should be omitted, leaving:

> The answer to your question can easily be found using a search engine so please do that. If you can't understand what you find, or why it answers your question, please ask a more specific question about the parts you don't understand.

Comment: If the commenter checks "an asshole", I don't think that's likely to change anytime soon. Plus, I don't think they'd be concerned about whether their comment would be obsolete later. They are, after all, an asshole